# Have table scrollable horizontally and accommodate few columns

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have a table which can have a range of columns, with this css below, I am able to get it scrollable horizontally with large number of columns:

```
.myTable {
    overflow:auto;
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}
```

But with 2-3 columns for example, the table shows up in partial page (horizontally) - doesn't span. Changing display to "table" makes the table with large number of columns overflow horizontally (scrolling is gone).

Any ideas how both cases can work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to move this table into a wrapper that itself has `overflow: scroll`, like so:

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
.myTable {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
      <th>Col 4</th>
      <th>Col 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <td>Data 2</td>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```